# Automate-Azure Active Directory Group Export to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a simple manual task that I need to automate in a sensible way.

I need to export the users and AD Object ID's of a specific group out of Azure Active Directory and drop a file off in Azure Data Lake or integrate directly in Azure SQL DB.

Powershell is not an option.  I am curious if there is anyone out there who has dealt this.  It sounds like Flow or Power Automate might allow for something like this but I am not sure where to start. I am using Data Factory as well and was wondering if there was a quick way to leverage that.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: No.  I will have to do research into your links.  I appreciate the feedback.  Using Graph API is what I preferred from the beginning so that is good at least haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the O365 linked service and dataset in Azure data factory which contains a feature of users extraction from the tenant.
So your source dataset can be O365 with users property and destination can be data lake with file type as Binary( a requirement for O365)

The below MSFT link explains the same:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-office-365